# Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ecmascript-6, websocket

I am new in react js development and try to integrate WebSocket un my app.

but got an error when I send messages during connection.

my code is

```
  const url = `${wsApi}/ws/chat/${localStorage.getItem("sID")}/${id}/`;


  const ws = new WebSocket(url);

  ws.onopen = (e) => {
    console.log("connect");
  };

  ws.onmessage = (e) => {
    const msgRes = JSON.parse(e.data);
    setTextMessage(msgRes.type);
    // if (msgRes.success === true) {
    //   setApiMessagesResponse(msgRes);
    // }
    console.log(msgRes);
  };
  // apiMessagesList.push(apiMessagesResponse);

  // console.log("message response", apiMessagesResponse);
  ws.onclose = (e) => {
    console.log("disconnect");
  };

  ws.onerror = (e) => {
    console.log("error");
  };

  const handleSend = () => {
    console.log(message);
    ws.send(message);
  };
```

and got this error

```
Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state
```

Comment: Where is `apiMessagesResponse` declared?

Comment: @Pointy this is a state that I use to set  API response... no concern with websocket

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're calling `ws.send` before the socket has completed the connection process. You need to wait for the `open` event/callback, or check the `readyState` per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Ready_state_constants) and queue the send after the `readyState` changes i.e after the `open` callback has fired.

Not suggesting you do this, but it might help:

```
const handleSend = () => {
  if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
    ws.send()
  } else {
    // Queue a retry
    setTimeout(() => { handleSend() }, 1000)
  }
};
```

As Logan has mentioned my first example is lazy. I just wanted to get OP unblocked and I trusted readers were intelligent enough to understand how to take it from there. So, make sure to handle the available states appropriately, e.g if `readyState` is `WebSocket.CONNECTING` then register a listener:

```
const handleSend = () => {
  if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
    ws.send()
  } else if (ws.readyState == WebSocket.CONNECTING) {
    // Wait for the open event, maybe do something with promises
    // depending on your use case. I believe in you developer!
    ws.addEventListener('open', () => handleSend())
  } else {
    // etc.
  }
};
```

Comment: You're welcome. I've improved the example to make my intent more clear.

Comment: Why `setTimeout` instead of listening for the `open` event? Using `setTimeout` for this is terrible.

Comment: All of your questions are addressed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can only send data with ws only if it's already open, and you do not check when it's open or not.

Basically you ask for an openning but you send a message before the server said it was open (it's not instant and you do not know how many time it can take ;) )

I think you should add a variable somithing like `let open = false;`

and rewrite the onopen

```
ws.onopen = (e) => {
    open = true;
    console.log("connect");
  };
```

and then in your logic you can only send a message if open is equal to true

don't forget the error handling ;)

Comment: btw you don't show us the backend so this message is only if the backend is perfect, else it may not open because of an error in the back

Comment: back end is developed by another developer. are you asking about a backend response?

Comment: @hannah no I was just telling that you didn't mentioned the fact that the backend was not yours so futurs problem could came from your back and so not the code you show us, but the code you did show us was missing the verification of the opening of the ws that should be it :P

Comment: thanks for your support. I've solved my problem:)